# Using String.Format inside a Binding

Tags: wpf, silverlight

In my XAML binding in a Silverlight App, I wrote something like this:

```
Text="{Binding TestSomething}"
```

`TestSomething` returns a number. Now I want to make a sentence out of it, for example something like:

> "We found this many XYZ results"

where XYZ is equal to that `TestSomething`

How can I combine `string.Format` with the binding above to generate the sentence that I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) binding specification:

```
Text="{Binding Path=TestSomething, StringFormat=We found this many {0} results}"
```